# jdb2 keeps Hard Disk busy all the time

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, io

My system became too slow last few days. The hard disk indicator is on all the time. To discover which process is keeping the disk busy i run this command:

```
# while true; do date; ps auxf | awk '{if($8=="D") print $0;}'; sleep 1; done | grep -v 2014
root       273  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Mar09  10:12  \_ [jbd2/sda7-8]
root       273  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Mar09  10:12  \_ [jbd2/sda7-8]
root       273  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Mar09  10:12  \_ [jbd2/sda7-8]
root       273  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Mar09  10:12  \_ [jbd2/sda7-8]
root       273  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Mar09  10:12  \_ [jbd2/sda7-8]
root       273  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Mar09  10:12  \_ [jbd2/sda7-8]
root       273  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Mar09  10:12  \_ [jbd2/sda7-8]
root       273  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Mar09  10:12  \_ [jbd2/sda7-8]
root       273  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Mar09  10:12  \_ [jbd2/sda7-8]
root       273  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Mar09  10:12  \_ [jbd2/sda7-8]
```

Unless there are many other programs including web browser, mysql-workbench, libreoffice, mediaplayer turning at the same time, but JDB2 is the top process using the system I/O !

How can i stop it safely or at least configure the system to disable it for the next boots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading your distribution should solve your problem.

Comment: I temporarily solved that by killing jdb2 process. But later i upgraded the dist. Indeed it's it was the  solution.